# How can i switch to dynamically changing iframe

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on the image within dynamically changing iframe. I have tried the following, but no luck. Help, please!

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'div_adnxs_tag_')]")));
```

This is the HTML

```
<div id="div_adnxs_tag_373.206035435957" style="">
<iframe width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" id="adnxs_tag_373.206035435957" name="adnxs_tag_373.206035435957" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" border="0" allowtransparency="true" style="visibility: visible; width: 728px; height: 90px;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@id, 'div_adnxs_tag_')]"}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the link to the target website you are testing against? Also, are there any `frameset` tags on the page?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]"}

Comment: you guys won't be able to get into the site...https

Comment: Have you tries with `explicit` wait?

Comment: Nice, Saifur!!!!!!   This did the trick    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]")));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the id of the iframe tag in xpath. In your case you are trying to switchTO frame using id of div tag.

```
By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_373')]"))
```

or

```
By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'adnxs_tag_')]"))
```

This should work.